# How to customize the selection form?

Tags: html, django

I have a model

```
class Car(models.Model):
  class ModelChoise(models.IntegerChoices):
    Model_1 = 0
    Model_2 = 1
    Model_3 = 2
    Model_4 = 3

  name = models.TextField('Name')
  model_id = models.IntegerField('model id', choices=ModelChoise.choices, default=1)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

And I created a form for it

```
class CarForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = ['model_id']
```

I need to deduce both key and value from it

```
{% for  mykey,myvalue in form.model_id %}
    {{ mykey }} : {{ myvalue }}
{% endfor %}
<!--
    Model_1 : 0
    Model_2 : 1
    Model_3 : 2
    Model_4 : 3
-->
```

How should I do it? I can only get the key.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why in the CarForm you point to the model ExtraUser... model_id seems to be a field in your Car model so I don't know why you reference it in a form pointing to a different model..

However when dealing with choices in templates you can go about it like this:

```
 {{ object.get_model_id_display }}
```

Basically get_ + field_name + _display will return the choice value

Comment: Sorry, I was sealed. It should have been `model = Car` I tried to use `{{ object.get_model_id_display }}` But it only returned the current value to me, example Model_2 and I need to get `1`

Comment: I see that you used the IntegerChoices class that was added in django 3.0, i actually haven't used this before. This is just a guess at this point but given that the class instance is an object in itself and you pass the Car model, maybe this is worth a try:

{{ object.choices.get_model_id_display }}

Comment: django didn't find the attribute `choices` I tried `{% for  mykey,myvalue in form.model_id %}{{ mykey }}:{{ myvalue }}{% endfor %}`
`{% for  mykey in form.model_id %}{{ mykey }}:{{ mykey.choices }}{% endfor %}`
`{% for  mykey in form.model_id %}{{ mykey }}:{{ mykey.val }}{% endfor %}`
`{% for  mykey in form.model_id %}{{ mykey }}:{{ mykey.value }}{% endfor %}`
`{% for  mykey in form.model_id %}{{ mykey }} : {{ mykey.id }}{% endfor %}` but nothing works